# Adding Methods to Constructors

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

**Refactor the carlike function in a way that allows us to use the method calling syntax with "dot access".**

```js
var carlike = function(obj, loc) {
  obj.loc = loc;
  return obj;
};

var move = function(car) {
  car.loc++;
};

var amy = carlike({}, 1);
var ben = carlike({}, 9);

/* 
Here we want to call move with "dot access"

amy.move();
ben.move();
*/
```

**THIS IS WHAT I'VE DONE...**

```js
var carlike = function(obj, loc) {
  obj.loc = loc;
  obj.move = move;//CHANGE#1
  return obj;
};

var move = function(car) {
  car.loc++;
};

var amy = carlike({}, 1);
var ben = carlike({}, 9);
amy.move();//CHANGE#2
ben.move();//CHANGE#3
```

**BUT IT WON'T WORK IT'S HAVING ERROR REGARDING LOCATION VARIABLE WHICH WAS WORKING GOOD UNTIL!**

*Thank You in Advance ☺*

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you're trying to execute function car without arguments, a proper solution should be change `move` function like this:

```
var move = function() {
  this.loc++;
};
```

Now, you're accessing to the object over the function is executed, in the first case `amy`, in the second `ben`. The final solution should be something like this.

```js
var carlike = function(obj, loc) {
  obj.loc = loc;
  obj.move = move;
  return obj;
};

var move = function() {
  this.loc++;
};

var amy = carlike({}, 1);
var ben = carlike({}, 9);
amy.move();
ben.move();
```

Comment: please remove the argument `car` from the `move` function. It's obsolete and misleading

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.move = move.bind(window,obj);
```

You may want to bind obj to the car parameter, so when you call move it gets automatically set. However, i would restructure the whole code like this (using class syntax):

```
class Car {
 constructor(val=0){
    this.loc=val;
 }
 move(distance=1){
  this.loc+=distance;
 }
 set(pos){
  this.loc=pos;
 }
}

var ben=new Car(10);
console.log(ben.loc);
ben.move();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var carlike = function(obj, loc) {
  obj.loc = loc;
  obj.move = move;//CHANGE#1
  return obj;
};

var move = function() {
  this.loc++;
  console.log(this.loc);
};

var amy = carlike({}, 1);
var ben = carlike({}, 9);
amy.move();//CHANGE#2
ben.move();//CHANGE#3
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you are considering your function `carlike`  as a constructor, then you must instantiate before you use, so that your code should be in object oriented way.

Answer to your question:

```
   var move = function() {
      this.loc++;
      console.log(this.loc);
    };

    var amy = new carlike({}, 1);
console.log(amy.move());
```

No need to pass params in move function, since you are using it inside your `carlike` constructor there for move function will become method and all context of `carlike` is also available for it. Thus you can use loc from context of `carlike` constructor (`this.loc`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to the current created object, you have to define the method inside the function which is constructing the object. like following code:

```js
var carlike = function(obj, loc) {
  obj.loc = loc;
  obj.move = function() {
     obj.loc++;
     console.log( obj.loc );
  }
  return obj;
};

var amy = carlike({}, 1);
var ben = carlike({}, 9);
amy.move();//CHANGE#2
ben.move();//CHANGE#3
```

as obj is created at runtime. if you refer the method externally like previous code snippets, the javascript interpreter does not know which object you are referring. yes there is an exception to that, like you can call the method as follows:

```
amy.move(amy);
ben.move(ben);
```

but writing that kind of code doesn't make any sense.